# Creating Pre-Authenticated Request in OCI

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, pre-authentication

I've an object storage bucket in OCI and I'm trying to create a Pre-Authenticated Request for an object in that bucket.
It gives me an error - **"Metadata must be no more than 3500 bytes when encoded as JSON in UTF-8. (MetadataTooLarge)"**.
I get the same error when I try to create a PAR for any bucket or object (inside bucket) in a particular compartment.

Where can I find the storage bucket metadata in OCI and how should I fix this error?

Comment: I think you have already indicated the solution. First of all, try the same moving the object to another compartment. If this works, check the tagging for that comparment (maybe you have a no-ended string or something like this)

Comment: I tried creating a new bucket in a different compartment and still creating a Pre Authenticated request gives the same error. However, when I tried using oci cli for creating PAR, it works fine.

Comment: Then, the only difference is create the PAR from console or from OCI CLI. Really strange! When I had this kind of problems, I open the debug window in console, and monitor the real call done by console.

Comment: not sure if it can help on your case:  Is the Object name very long? Or are you using a federated user member of many groups?